# Toggle between linear and log scale in bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

How can I re-generate [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/logaxis.html) toggling between linear and log scales?

Background: I'm a long-time Matplotlib user, recent Bokeh user. 
One of the main reasons I have started using Bokeh is because of the interactiveness it provides. A big part of it would be the ability to toggle between linear and log scales in plots (which is something I really need in my daily life). This question was adressed [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2765) in 2015 and at the time there was no clear answer.

However, it's 2 years later and I'm wondering if there's a way to include a button/widget to change from linear to log scale for both the x and the y axes. If there isn't, I'm certain that there is a clean way to simulate that behavior in some way (without having two plots side-by-side).

Comment: Now that `Scale` is a public model instead of hidden implementation details, this is much more reasonable to contemplate. Please feel free to open a GitHub issue to discuss it https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues Until then, the answer below is probably the best workaround.

Comment: @bigreddot Started it [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6575) if you're interested

Comment: Yup, I've been commenting on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is the put both linear and log plots into Tabs like:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs, Panel

panels = []

for axis_type in ["linear", "log"]:
    fig = figure(x_axis_type=axis_type, y_axis_type=axis_type)
    fig.scatter(x=[1,10,100,1000], y=[1,10,100,1000])

    panel = Panel(child=fig, title=axis_type)
    panels.append(panel)

tabs = Tabs(tabs=panels)

show(tabs)
```

Alternatively, you wire up a `bokeh.models.widgets.Button` with a CustomJS callback that changes the plot ranges, but the above seems a little easier to me.

Comment: I store 9 figures for a `gridplot` in a dictionary (so I can iterate over it when e.g. the data or title should change). With the current solution I would need to rewrite the code in many occurences since an additional layer in my dictionary (or a second dictionary) for log/linear would be needed, or do you see an easy solution for this when using Panel and Tabs?